# How to Mimic a Continue Statement in a Cursor-For-Loop in Oracle 10G PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, continue

In Oracle 10g, there is no continue statement. Typically it is mimicked in an explicit cursor like such:

```
OPEN c_cur ;
<<cont>>
LOOP
    ...
    IF condition = 10 THEN
        GOTO cont ;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c_cur ;
```

Given that the LOOP keyword immediately follows the cursor in the cursor-for-loop syntax, how can a continue statement be mimicked?

```
FOR rec IN c_cur LOOP
    ...
END LOOP ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR rec IN c_cur LOOP
    ...
    IF condition = 10 THEN
        GOTO cont ;
    END IF ;

<<CONT>>
NULL; -- END cannot be immediately preceeded by a <<marker>>

END LOOP ;
```

Answer (score -1):

use [`CONTINUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/continue_statement.htm)

```
FOR rec IN c_cur LOOP
    IF condition = 10 THEN
        CONTINUE;
    END IF ;
END LOOP ;
```

Comment: I believe OP's point was that CONTINUE is not available in 10g.

Comment: Also note that CONTINUE is bugged in 11gR1. Oracle's PL/SQL optimizer uses BULK operations internally and call to `CONTINUE` will jump 100 records forward (not only one).